# Create a PDF in illustrator with links to pages

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, adobe-acrobat

Is it possible to create a multi-page PDF using Adobe Illustrator with various elements on a page linked to other pages in same PDF?

The purpose is, we want to output semi-interactive prototypes with Illustrator.

EDIT on receiving a possible duplicate:
My question is about creating links that point to different pages in the same file, not an Internet address. (something like #page3)

Answer (score 2):

No. Illustrator can not create interactive PDFs.

You can generate the PDF with Illustrator then add interaction using Acrobat. Or you can create interactive PDFs with InDesign.

Answer (score 1):

> No. Illustrator can not create interactive PDFs.
>
> You can generate the PDF with Illustrator then add interaction using
>   Acrobat. Or you can create interactive PDFs with InDesign.

To add to Scott's answer you can add JavaScript but you will be required to have Acrobat Pro because Acrobat Standard will not allow you but that is based on my experience with Acrobat 10 and not 11.

You can do bookmarking in Acrobat and if you already have a `.pdf` file there is no reason to involve Illustrator.

[image]

Great `.pdf` file from [academic.umn.edu](http://www.academic.umn.edu/provost/faculty/tenure/documents/bookmarks.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

**You can easily add links that go from one page to another in your PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro.**

You can add links anywhere you want, make them visible or not, it's up to you. Perfect for table of contents or to send a reader to a source for example.

---

## Adding links and page tags/anchors to a PDF

1. Simply use your selection tool and trace a rectangle where you want the link to be (the "button"), then right-click to see a menu. Select "create link"

[image]

2. Then select the option you prefer for your link... in this case "go to a page" view. Click "next".

[image]

3. After this, you will need to go to the actual page of your PDF to select which page the link will send people to when clicked. Once you are on the destination page, click "set link".

[image]

---

## Bookmarks

You can add "Bookmarks" in a similar way using the right-click on the page that needs to be bookmarked. Or select the text that needs to be bookmarked and then right-click/add bookmark, it will be added directly in the bookmarks panel. Then it's possible to re-order these bookmarks in groups if you want.

**If you want people to actually see the bookmark panel, you'll need to set this in your PDF Document Properties (Initial View tab/navigation tab/bookmark panel and pages)**

---

If you can add html code in your Illustrator, then you could always try to do it the same way as for any webpage, and use the html anchor code, and link to them. I've never tried it, I don't know if it works in Illustrator.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/565216